# Wierd null value gets inserted into Hive table for Date & timestamp column

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table (say table1) with 2 columns date & timestamp datatypes. I loaded csv data into table1 using the below command

load data local inpath '/home/praveen/abc.csv' into table table1 ;

I could see the values properly loaded into the table.

Now I created another table (say table2) which is exactly same as table1 and I tried to load data into that using this command

insert into table2 select * from table1;

But I could see null values inserted into table2.

I want to perform some date manipulation in table2. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: check data type and also select * from table1 is not generating null value.

Comment: Select * from table1 gives proper results and I don't see any null values. Data types of both tables are same. Date format is yyyy-dd-mm e.g 2016-05-31 and TimeStamp  format is yyyy-dd-mm HH:MM:SS e.g 2016-05-31 09:30:55

Comment: is null value appearing through out table ..?

Comment: It seems like if the date format is yyyy-mm-dd then hive automatically loads data into the table. I formatted the date column in the input csv file and I could see that date is properly imported into the table and no NULL value. Source : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-date  hive automatically load data from csv